# PAAS with triplestore?

Tags: rdf, paas

Does anyone know of a PAAS that provides a RDF triplestore as as a storage option? My google foo has failed me.

I'm looking for a triplestore similar to OpenRDF/sesame with RDFS and OWL inferencing support. The PAAS would preferably support ruby and nodejs. Any language suppot is fine though...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

[Dydra](http://dydra.com/) I think would qualify as PaaS, but I don't think they do any inferencing.  I could be wrong, but I think that's the case, you'd want to double check before crossing them off the list.

[Stardog](http://stardog.com), while not PaaS, does provide scalable RDFS and OWL2 profiles inference.  It provides API bindings for Sesame's Repository API, and has a pretty well documented HTTP API and native protocol based on Google's protocol buffers.  A javascript library that implements the HTTP API is slated for release in the coming weeks.

[OWLIM](http://www.ontotext.com/owlim), similar to Stardog, is an rdf database, which I think provides RDFS & OWL2 RL inference.  I know they provide support for Sesame's Repository API, but I don't know if they also implement their HTTP API.  Might be an option if you're sticking to Java only.

Disclaimer is that I am the lead dev of Stardog.